# DataFrame String Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe that has one column with data that looks like this:

```
AAH.
AAH.
AAR.UN
AAR.UN
AAR.UN
AAR.UN
AAV.
AAV.
AAV.
```

I think I need to use the apply method to trim the column data. So if there is anything after the period keep the data unchanged but if there is nothing after the period then return just the letters without the period at the end. I know I can probably use a lambda function and maybe a string split or something to do this but have not much of an idea to make it happen.

This is kind of what I have so far:

```
df.apply(lambda x: string.split('.'))
```

I am not sure if I can use an if statement or something with the lambda function this way?

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to receive at the end? split returns list, is it what you want?

Comment: No, I am really looking to just get the value of the string so either being AAV or AAR.UN, I guess I am trying to vectorize the whole column in one shot kinda

Answer (score 2):

Since there's only one column, you can take advantage of vectorized string operations via `.str` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)):

```
>>> df
        0
0    AAH.
1    AAH.
2  AAR.UN
3  AAR.UN
4  AAR.UN
5  AAR.UN
6    AAV.
7    AAV.
8    AAV.
>>> df[0] = df[0].str.rstrip('.')
>>> df
        0
0     AAH
1     AAH
2  AAR.UN
3  AAR.UN
4  AAR.UN
5  AAR.UN
6     AAV
7     AAV
8     AAV
```

Otherwise you'd have to do something like `df.applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip("."))`, or drop down to numpy `char` methods.

Comment: actually I have 3 columns but would this work the same if I specify what col I want this to work on?

Comment: @tbonejo: yep, there's nothing special about `0`, and you could loop over `df.columns` if you wanted to.  If you know they're all strings (with no missing values) then the `applymap` approach is also an option.

Comment: Not sure why but I cannot seem to get this to work as it just errors that it could not find the key. One thing I did not mention was I get the df from the xls.parse function.

Comment: I think my issue with this not working is that this is not a series?

Comment: The column *is* a Series.  Without more specifics about what the error is, it's hard to help.

Comment: @tbonejo: Try `df[0].str.rstrip('. \t\r\n')`. This will remove periods, spaces, tabs, and end-of-line characters from the end of each string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda function to do this:

```
>>> L = [['AAH.'],
         ['AAR.UN'],
         ['AAR.UN'],
         ['AAV.'],
         ['AAV.']]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(L)
>>> M = lambda x: x[0][:-1] if x[0][-1]=='.' else x[0][:]
>>> df = df.apply(M, axis=1)

>>> df
0       AAH
1    AAR.UN
2    AAR.UN
3       AAV
4       AAV
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_to_date(string):
    seq = (string[:2],string[2:5],string[5:])
    return '-'.join(seq)

pt['DATE'] = pt['DATE'].apply(change_to_date)
```

I applied a simple function to the column to manipulate all string values, for somewhat similar problem.